# Masking data frame with multidimensional key

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame containing `value_1` and `value_2`

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "id_1": [101, 202],
        "id_2": [101, 202],
        "value_1": [5.0, 10.0],
        "value_2": [10.0, 4.0],
    }
)
df_1 = df_1.set_index(["id_1", "id_2"])
```

that looks like this:

```
           value_1  value_2
id_1 id_2
101  101       5.0     10.0
202  202      10.0      4.0
```

I have another data frame, that contains a flag for each value, i.e. `is_active_1` and `is_active_2`:

```
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "id_1": [101, 202],
        "id_2": [101, 202],
        "is_active_1": [True, False],
        "is_active_2": [False, False],
    }
)
df_2 = df_2.set_index(["id_1", "id_2"])
```

that looks like this:

```
           is_active_1  is_active_2
id_1 id_2
101  101          True        False
202  202         False        False
```

I want to multiply the `value` rows by `*3` in `df_1` depending on its flag in `df_2`. The end result should like this:

```
           value_1  value_2
id_1 id_2
101  101      15.0     10.0
202  202      10.0      4.0
```

i.e. the `is_active_1 = True` flag for `(id_1, id_2) = (101, 101)` causes `value_1 -> 3 * 5.0 = 15.0`

I have tried the following:

```
df_1.loc[df_2[["is_active_1", "is_active_2"]], ["value_1", "value_2"]] * 3
```

but ended up with a value error `ValueError: Cannot index with multidimensional key`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By decreasing level of index alignment.

You can [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) the columns to replace `is_active` by `name`:

```
df_1[df_2.rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace('is_active', 'value'))] *= 3
```

Or, you can use [`set_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html) to avoid index alignment on the columns:

```
df_1[df_2.set_axis(df_1.columns, axis=1)] *= 3
```

Or assume the two dataframes are aligned and ignore completely the labels of `df_2`:

```
df_1[df_2.to_numpy()] *= 3
```

Updated `df_1`:

```
           value_1  value_2
id_1 id_2                  
101  101      15.0     10.0
202  202      10.0      4.0
```